# Create a list and reference certain cell if true

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Right now I have a column(M) that lists either yes/no. I need to create a list that references the value in column A if the value in column M is equal to no. I'm able to reference the cell correctly but I'm not able to create a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this at the top of an unused column and fill down,

=index(a:a, aggregate(15, 6, row($1:$999)/(m$1:m$999="no"), row(1:1)))

Comment: Why doesn't this work if I choose to do another column that has dollar values in it? Tried switching to...

{=INDEX(A:A, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/(N$1:N$999>999.99), ROW(1:1)))}

Comment: The 'dollar signs' should be added through cell formatting (e.g. Currency style) and you should be matching the raw underlying numeric values (e.g. 5.9) not the displayed value (e.g. $ 5.90).

Comment: That formula should work. I believe your currency is actually text masquerading as real numbers. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUs0z.png

Comment: It's just returning a value of zero. I've changed the formatting to be reflected as just numbers with no currency formatting. The value i'm trying to return is a text value in column a.

Comment: Hmm, I dont fix the text masquerading?

Comment: If you turned the currency into numbers and the $ went away then you have true numbers. I'm at a loss. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUs0z.png

Comment: I figured it out, my bad. Thank you for the help.